# How to retrieve stored message in mailgun messages api for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, mailgun, rest-client

I am using mailgun to convert incoming emails to post requests for my rails app, and that part is working fine, but I also want to be able to retrieve stored messages from the mailgun messages API, and am having trouble accomplishing that. The docs for their messages api is:

https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#retrieving-stored-messages

To make things easier I installed the RestClient gem in my rails app and have hacked around with it in rails console, but cannot get the full email object to return.

EDIT - I can make a successful get request to the stored message URL using the Postman application, using basic authorization with 'api' for username and my api key for password. But when I try to make this request using the rest-client gem, it gives me a `401 unauthorized` error. Here's my attempt from inside the console of my rails app.

```
url = 'https://se.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/rest-of-the-url...'
user = 'api'
secret ='my-api-key'

RestClient::Request.execute method: :get, url: url, username: user, password: secret
```

Comment: hello... include a better explanation of the problem and point us to the code that is not working or that you do not understand

Comment: Edited question to add more detail including my code for making a get request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it wasn't working before, but for anyone who's curious, this method using rest-client gem seems to do the trick!

```
url = [url of stored email]
user = 'api'
secret ='my-api-key'

response = RestClient::Request.execute method: :get, url: url, user: user, password: secret
email = JSON.parse(response.body) # the email object!
```